# Stress Testing VPS

Tags: vps, stress-testing

Anyone ever stress test a VPS. Or know of any custom stress tests that would work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run a stress test on a VPS just as you would on any other system. This could involve:

- Using ab ([Apache benchmark](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html)) to simulate http hits;
- [Linux benchmark suite](http://lbs.sourceforge.net/)
- [Jmeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/index.html) from Apache.

Of course that is assuming you are speaking of a Linux VPS,  but you didn't mention your OS, so if you are using another one such as Windows they also have benchmark tools available.

Comment: Dreamhost uses linux. So All this should work.

Comment: +1 - I'd also do this at 3 or 4 different times of the day, during the week and over weekends (to get an idea of how the other users on the VPS hosting infrastructure may affect performance).